# Looping in my array of errors (key/value) in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a variable with some data (key/value):

```
var errors = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

Here is the content:

```
 {
 "vehicle.Model":"Le champ Model est requis.",
 "vehicle.Brand":"Le champ Brand est requis.",
 "vehicle.Registration":"Le champ Registration est requis."
 }
```

I would like to loop into it and display the key and the value for each.

How to proceed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var key;

for (key in errors) {
   if (errors.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(key + " : " + errors[key]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `hasOwnProperty` if you just got the object using `JSON.parse`.

Comment: always check the 'hasOwnProperty' so you dont end up in the prototype chain.

Comment: Always using `hasOwnProperty` is a good practice IMO, regardless of where the data is coming from, although this is not mandatory here. Code review and further maintenance / evolution will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var key in errors) {
   var code = key;
   var label = errors[key];
   ...
}
```

Note that there is no guarantee regarding the iteration order in today's ECMAScript.

I'd recommend you to read MDN's [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: You're not using the `code` variable (it seems useless anyway).

Answer (score 0):

```
for( key in errors ){console.log(key + " = " + errors.key);}
```